# type cast to integer

Tags: c++, casting, char

Suppose I have

```
    unsigned char * buffer; // buffer len in 10000
```

I want to convert buffer+50 to buffer+54 to int. The following code works

```
    int c=(*((int *) (buffer+ 32));
```

But is there any better way to do this and how much instruction it should take ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assemble the integer from the bytes directly via shift operations. It will both worth and be portable, including platforms with 64-bit `int`. As written, woe be unto you if the offset you're using doesn't fall on memory properly aligned for your platform to access as an `int` (cheating death by running on x86 hardware not withstanding). And you better already know the endianness of the inbound data.

Comment: In addition to what @WhozCraig says, by reading each char and shifting/oring into your result, you have precise control of the endianness of your storage, where by just writing code that says "give me the integer at this address" you either rely on the endianness of your host CPU or you're required to know to swap the values around.

Comment: Read http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am aware of endianness. I am going to run on same endianness and 64 bits. I am working to low latency project. would this work if i ignore endianness and I use same CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
std::uint32_t convert_to_int32(std::uint8_t* buffer) // assume size 4
{
    std::uint32_t result = (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[0]) << 24) |
                           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[1]) << 16) |
                           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[2]) << 8) |
                           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[3]));
    return result;
}
```

The main problem you will have with your current method is if you run into alignment issues (e.g. you attempt to cast the integer pointer from a point in the buffer that is not on an integer alignment barrier).  The shifting method gets around that.